# what is better Doing AJAX call or use UpdatePanel for updating a panel?

Tags: asp.net, ajax, panel, call

In my application i need to update a panels content after the button click which do some server side processing. I don't want to do full page postback.
I can achieve this in two ways : By doing a AJAX call or by using a update panel. But I am confused to choose one. Which is a better option in this case?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Doing your own AJAX will be more efficient but the Update Panel will be easier to implement. An Update Panel postback is almost as large as a full one - if you do everything yourself with something like jQuery you have much more control over what gets sent.

I recommend reading this: http://encosia.com/2007/07/11/why-aspnet-ajax-updatepanels-are-dangerous/

Comment: Thank you Radu.. After follow the article I am going for the AJAX call. It works excellent..